# How to automate the modification of code?

Tags: text, vim, automation, editor

I have a large piece of code consisting of **thousands** of equations. Example of two connective lines, corresponding to lines  998 and 999 is

```
sum(x[i]*y[i]for i in 1:n) == 15;
sum(z[i]*x[i]for i in 1:n) == 30;
```

I would like to replace such lines with the following

```
sum(x[i]*y[i]for i in 1:n) - 15 >= -s[998];
sum(x[i]*y[i]for i in 1:n) - 15 <=  s[998];

sum(z[i]*x[i]for i in 1:n) - 30 >= -s[999];
sum(z[i]*x[i]for i in 1:n) - 30 <=  s[999];
```

How to automate this process?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @romainl I was able to change == to - in microsoft words and duplicate each line in vim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Substitutions

Our first step is to transform each individual line:

```
sum(x[i]*y[i]for i in 1:n) == 15;
```

into this:

```
sum(x[i]*y[i]for i in 1:n) - 15 >= -s[998];
```

While doing it in one command would be a nice parlor trick, we will do it in several easier to follow steps.

1. `==` to `-`

   Here is our first command, it is very simple:

   ```
   :%s/==/-<CR>
   ```

   - `:` enters command-line mode.
   - `%` is the range of lines on which to execute the following command. Here, `%` is a shortcut for `1,$` (from line 1 to last line), thus "every line".
   - `s` is the "substitute" command, see `:help :s`.
   - `/==` is what you want to substitute.
   - `/-` is what you want to substitute it with.
   - Press `<CR>` (ENTER) to execute the command.

   In plain english: "substitute every `==` with `-`".

   We should get something like:

   ```
   sum(x[i]*y[i]for i in 1:n) - 15;
   sum(z[i]*x[i]for i in 1:n) - 30;
   ```
2. `;` to `>= -s[XXX];`

   Here is our second command:

   ```
   :%s/;/ >= -s[XXX];
   ```

   Where we substitute every `;` with a generic  `>= -s[XXX];`. This is also quite simple.

   In plain english: "substitute every `;` with  `>= -s[XXX];`.

   We should get something like:

   ```
   sum(x[i]*y[i]for i in 1:n) - 15 >= -s[XXX];
   sum(z[i]*x[i]for i in 1:n) - 30 >= -s[XXX];
   ```
3. `XXX` to line number

   Here is our third command:

   ```
   :%s/XXX/\=line('.')
   ```

   The big change between this command and the other ones is that the replacement part is dynamic. With `\=`, we use an expression that is evaluated during each execution instead of a fixed string. `line('.')` is a vimscript function that returns a line number, which is exactly what we want between those brackets.

   In plain english: "substitute every `XXX` with the current line number".

   We should get something like:

   ```
   sum(x[i]*y[i]for i in 1:n) - 15 >= -s[998];
   sum(z[i]*x[i]for i in 1:n) - 30 >= -s[999];
   ```

### Duplication

Here we duplicate each line with a single command:

```
:g/^/t.|s/-s/ s
```

- `:g` is the `:help :global` command.
- `/^/` matches every line so the following command will be executed on every line.
- `t` is the `:help :t` command.
- `.` represents the current line.
- `|` separates two commands.
- `s/-s/ s` removes the `-` before the `s` on the duplicated line.

In plain english: "mark every line, then copy each marked line below itself, then remove that leading `-` before the `s`".

We should get something like:

```
sum(x[i]*y[i]for i in 1:n) - 15 >= -s[998];
sum(x[i]*y[i]for i in 1:n) - 15 >=  s[998];
sum(z[i]*x[i]for i in 1:n) - 30 >= -s[999];
sum(z[i]*x[i]for i in 1:n) - 30 >=  s[999];
```

### One last thing

We use one last command to add a line between our blocks:

```
:g/ s[/put=''
```

- Every line matching  `s[` is marked.
- We use `:help :put` to append an empty line.

In plain english: "put an empty line after each line with  `s[`".

We should get something like:

```
sum(x[i]*y[i]for i in 1:n) - 15 >= -s[998];
sum(x[i]*y[i]for i in 1:n) - 15 >=  s[998];

sum(z[i]*x[i]for i in 1:n) - 30 >= -s[999];
sum(z[i]*x[i]for i in 1:n) - 30 >=  s[999];
```

### What did we learn?

- how to perform simple substitutions with `:help :substitute`,
- the notion of `:help :range`,
- how to use an expression in the replacement part (the usual gateway drug to vimscript) with `:help sub-replace-\=`,
- how to execute arbitrary commands on lines matching a specific pattern with `:help :global`,
- how to copy a given line to a given address with `:help :t`,
- how to put some text, here an empty string, below the current line with `:help :put`,
- how to separate commands with `:help :|`.